# Astra Camera Shows in rviz, Invalid device number in openni2

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-indigo, astra

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: Thanks to @gvdhoorn for the input - I think that it's confirming what I seem to be finding out. By simply running the Astra drivers in place of the OpenNI2 drivers, I'm able to see the images from the Turtlebot as explained in the tutorial. I think that, with the new sensor, I simply have to use the Orbec drivers rather than the OpenNI drivers.

The problem now becomes that, once I get to the point in the tutorial that I'm using `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch` on the Turtlebot and `roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch` on the workstation, the frames are not correctly configured to work with everything else. Here's what I've done so far to try to address the configuration issue:

- `3dsensor.launch` appears to use the `TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR` environment variable to get the appropriate launch.xml file, so I don't think that there are any changes necessary here. However, there are a number of variables that get re-mapped here that I think may be relevant to getting what the Astra driver outputs to match up to what the Turtlebot looks for.
- In `/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/launch/includes/3dsensor`, I copied `kinect.launch.xml` to `astra.launch.xml`, the only difference between the files being that the include portion points to `astra_launch/launch/astra.launch` rather than `freenect_launch/launch/freenect.launch`. If I understand correctly, this configures the system to use the launch file from the Astra driver when the `3dsensor.launch` file is used to start the 3d sensor system on the turtlebot.
- I notice that the freenect package appears to have a file that points to `kinect_frames.launch` in the rgbd_launch project, which looks like it defines transforms for the camera. Simply making a copy of that file over to the astra_launch project and linking it to the `astra.launch` file doesn't appear to fix the problem. I'm still getting an error in rviz saying that camera_rgb_optical_frame does not exist. Since this frame is defined by what is now `astra_frames.launch`, I'm guessing that this reference frame has to match an existing reference frame in the overall robot model to link the two? Because camera_rgb_optical_frame is not an option in the Global Options->Fixed Frame or the Grid->Reference Frame

I think that I need to look for some kind of tutorial on reference frames to better understand what is going on here and how I might be able to resolve it. Again, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

I'm working my way through the Turtlebot tutorials (http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/8/), and I'm currently at the stage where I'm testing the 3D sensor. I'm running into a few problems since the Turtlebot that I purchased came with ROS installed on the laptop, but apparently not correctly configured. The sensor that came included is the Orbec Astra, which I had to go out separately to find drivers and such for. I can give that history if it's relevant, but given the symptoms I'm thinking that there is just some configuration subtlety that I'm missing.

**Configuration**

I'm working with a Turtlebot 2 using a Lenovo Thinkpad running Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo.

**What Works**

As a part of testing the Orbec Astra driver that I installed, I can run the following command successfully:

```
roslaunch astra_launch astra.launch
```

This produces the following output:

> ```
> turtlebot@turtlebot:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch astra_launch astra.launch 
> ... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/862942be-1e5a-11e9-b052-7c7a9105e52e/roslaunch-turtlebot-19111.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
> Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
> Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server http://localhost:53104/
>
> SUMMARY
> ========
>
> PARAMETERS
>  * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads: 4
>  * /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
>  * /camera/driver/auto_exposure: True
>  * /camera/driver/auto_white_balance: True
>  * /camera/driver/bootorder: 0
>  * /camera/driver/color_depth_synchronization: False
>  * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url: 
>  * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id: camera_depth_opti...
>  * /camera/driver/depth_registration: False
>  * /camera/driver/device_id: #1
>  * /camera/driver/devnums: 1
>  * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url: 
>  * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id: camera_rgb_optica...
>  * /rosdistro: indigo
>  * /rosversion: 1.11.10
>
> NODES
>   /camera/
>     camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
>     depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
>     depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
>     depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
>     depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
>     driver (nodelet/nodelet)
>     points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
>     rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
>     register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
>   /
>     camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>     camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>     camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>     camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>
> auto-starting new master
> process[master]: started with pid [19123]
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> setting /run_id to 862942be-1e5a-11e9-b052-7c7a9105e52e
> process[rosout-1]: started with pid [19136]
> started core service [/rosout]
> process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-2]: started with pid [19153]
> process[camera/driver-3]: started with pid [19154]
> [ INFO] [1548170976.456609336]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
> process[camera/rectify_color-4]: started with pid [19190]
> process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-5]: started with pid [19204]
> [ INFO] [1548170976.548044840]: Device "2bc5/0401@2/4" found.
> Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
> process[camera/depth_metric_rect-6]: started with pid [19234]
> process[camera/depth_metric-7]: started with pid [19289]
> process[camera/depth_points-8]: started with pid [19317]
> process[camera/register_depth_rgb-9]: started with pid [19331]
> process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-10]: started with pid [19345]
> process[camera_base_link-11]: started with pid [19359]
> process[camera_base_link1-12]: started with pid [19372]
> process[camera_base_link2-13]: started with pid [19383]
> process[camera_base_link3-14]: started with pid [19410]
> ```

With this running, I can go into rviz, add topic /camera/depth/points/PointCloud2, set the Fixed Frame, and I can see the point cloud displayed in the grid. My understanding is that this indicates that the driver is installed correctly.

**What Doesn't Work**

According to the [Turtlebot tutorial](http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/8/), the next step in verifying the depth sensor is to test it using the OpenNI package. Per the instructions, I bring up the Turtlebot in the minimal configuration and then run with openni. I've tried both versions available on my system: openni and openni2, the latter of which was installed trying to get the Astra camera working in the first place. Here's the output that I'm seeing:

> ```
> turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch 
> >     ... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/33ff7e72-1e5f-11e9-86f8-7c7a9105e52e/roslaunch-turtlebot-28502.log
> >     Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
> >     Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
> >     Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
> >     
> >     unused args [depth_registered_filtered] for include of [/opt/ros/indigo/share/rgbd_launch/launch/includes/processing.launch.xml]
> >     The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
> >     turtlebot@turtlebot:~$ roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch 
> ... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/33ff7e72-1e5f-11e9-86f8-7c7a9105e52e/roslaunch-turtlebot-28609.log
> Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
> Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
> Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> started roslaunch server http://localhost:47625/
>
> SUMMARY
> ========
>
> PARAMETERS
>  * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads: 4
>  * /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation: 0
>  * /camera/driver/auto_exposure: True
>  * /camera/driver/auto_white_balance: True
>  * /camera/driver/color_depth_synchronization: False
>  * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url: 
>  * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id: camera_depth_opti...
>  * /camera/driver/depth_registration: False
>  * /camera/driver/device_id: #1
>  * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url: 
>  * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id: camera_rgb_optica...
>  * /rosdistro: indigo
>  * /rosversion: 1.11.10
>
> NODES
>   /camera/
>     camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
>     depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
>     depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
>     depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
>     depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
>     driver (nodelet/nodelet)
>     points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
>     rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
>     register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
>   /
>     camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>     camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>     camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>     camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
>
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> core service [/rosout] found
> process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [28628]
> process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [28636]
> [ INFO] [1548173016.697688262]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
> process[camera/rectify_color-3]: started with pid [28667]
> process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-4]: started with pid [28682]
> [ INFO] [1548173016.819368063]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.3-0trusty-20150327-0611/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
> process[camera/depth_metric_rect-5]: started with pid [28710]
> process[camera/depth_metric-6]: started with pid [28725]
> process[camera/depth_points-7]: started with pid [28742]
> process[camera/register_depth_rgb-8]: started with pid [28757]
> process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-9]: started with pid [28772]
> process[camera_base_link-10]: started with pid [28787]
> process[camera_base_link1-11]: started with pid [28799]
> process[camera_base_link2-12]: started with pid [28811]
> process[camera_base_link3-13]: started with pid [28823]
> [ INFO] [1548173019.819603347]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.3-0trusty-20150327-0611/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
> [ INFO] [1548173022.819789168]: No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&) @ /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.3-0trusty-20150327-0611/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 : Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
> ```

This looks to me like the OpenNI2 driver doesn't know the right port or the right configuration for the Astra camera, but I'm not sure where that would be defined that I could fix it. My plan at the moment is to look at the difference between the astra.launch and openni2.launch files to see if I can see where the ports are defined. I'm also planning to look at the URDF file, since I copied that from the Kinect and I think that the two connect differently. I'm posting this here both for help and so that I can document any solution I find in case anyone else runs into the same problem. Help is very much appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313385/astra-camera-shows-in-rviz,-invalid-device-number-in-openni2/) by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2019-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-22**:
I'm not an expert on this topic, so take this as additional input, but: I believe the tutorial you link to assumes a "regular" TB2 (ie: old one) that came with either a Kinect *or* an Xtion.

After those became (very) hard to purchase, a switch was made to the Astra. I'm not sure OpenNI ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-22**:
.. stuff can be used with that camera, but again, I'm not an expert.

The driver (most likely) doesn't care about the URDF. What would be important would be for the respective topics to exist after you've launched the driver. Seeing as you can see a pointcloud in RViz, I would say they are, and ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-22**:
.. you should be able to continue from there.

I'm not sure what the status of the Astra integration into the TB2 pkgs is. I've never used/needed it, as I only have old TB2s here, with Kinects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you checked the Kinetic version of the Turtlebot packages? That has standardised on the Astra. See [Alternative 3D Sensor Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Alternative%203D%20Sensor%20Setup) fi.

It appears the (recent) Indigo version of `turtlebot_bringup` already seems to include infrastructure for the Astra, so you may want to check whether you have the latest upgrades for Indigo on your system as well.

---

Edit:

> using the tutorials on learn.turtlebot.com , I thought that I was still meant to be using the OpenNI drivers [..]

thing is: those tutorials were created by members of the community.

Software evolves, and if artefacts like those tutorials don't get updated, you run into situations like this.

It's really unfortunate, but it's a common problem with documentation and support material.

The `learnturtlebot.com` sources are hosted at [turtlebot/learn.turtlebot.com](https://github.com/turtlebot/learn.turtlebot.com). Perhaps you could submit a PR that makes this clearer for future readers? You're in a unique position to do so, having just overcome the confusion of trying to understand the current material and mapping your insights to a newer version of the software stack.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on 2019-01-23**:
Thanks - I am actually a little hamstrung in that my work environment limits my access to the Internet, so one of the reasons we bought this particular robot was that it was supposed to come with ROS installed and ready to go. Since that's not the case already, I'll try that. Thanks!

**Comment by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on 2019-01-23**:
I think that this is working now. I took your advice and re-installed ROS and turtlebot, using the Kinetic version. Astra is supported by default as you said - what confused me for a little bit is that, using the tutorials on learn.turtlebot.com, I thought that I was still meant to be using the...

**Comment by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on 2019-01-23**:
...OpenNI drivers. If I run astra_launch where it says to run openni_launch, everything works fine, and the turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch works just fine, too. I'd like to give you credit for the solution. Would you mind writing this up as an answer so I can do so?

**Comment by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on 2019-01-25**:
Thank you again for the help! And I'd be happy to contribute - PR is a pull request? If I'm understanding the process correctly, I'll pull the repository, make changes to the tutorial files, and then submit a request that those changes get pulled into the main? If that's the case, I'm going to have

**Comment by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on 2019-01-25**:
to figure out a way to do that from home, since our security policies at work prevent that kind of thing. But it would be nice to give back after all the help the open source community has given me!